# number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 5) in R

Tags: r

This is the function I use when trying to generate a pairwise correlation data:

```
pairs(~bedroom+bathroom+parking+taxes+lotsize,
      data=x,gap=0.4,cex.labels=0.85)
numericx=cbind(bedroom,bathroom,parking,taxes,lotsize)
round(cor(numericxy,use = "complete.obs"), 4)
pairs(sale~bedroom+bathroom+parking+taxes+lotsize,data=x,cex.labels=0.85)
numericxy=cbind(sale,numericx)
round(cor(numericxy), 4)
```

This is the data:

[image: This is what the dataset looks like]

I am wondering how to correct this error: the number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 5).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal  reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can help you easier. Ideally, also include example data using `dput()`.